# Can I settle at the Tenpenny Tower without destroying Megaton?

Tags: fallout-3

I am curious if I could settle at the Tenpenny Tower without blowing up the Megaton bomb and becoming evil (and if this is possible even after I disarm the bomb and fail the Mr Burk's quest to detonate it). Can I? If yes - how?

Answer (score 12):

You cannot.

Mr Burk will only give you the key to your room as a quest reward for setting off the bomb.  Even killing him doesn't get you the key.

Comment: Even if you cheat to get the keys, the room will not be assigned to you, which means you can't decorate it, store anything in it, sleep in the bed ... basically its just a room.

Comment: Ah, that's true.  I recall trying that.  I'll fix my answer.

Comment: I can't get on the wiki right now, but can't you take over the tower with the ghouls without destroying Megaton?  Or does that not grant you the room?

Answer (score 3):

If you are playing on PC then there are mods for this. I use one called [Tenpenny Suite After Saving Megaton](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout3/mods/2625/) where you get the suite after dealing with the ghoul Roy and his gang.

Answer (score 2):

Though i have not tested this, You may be able to do this by cheating using the command console. Y U NO WORK pointed out even hacking the key does not give you ownership, but with many Bethesda games, you can skip events without actually doing them to obtain the key the "proper" way by using the command console, (cheating). Through the command console, you can give yourself any quest and set it to almost any point (called the stage). there are 3 parts to this command, and all 3 can be obtained from the wiki, with 2 of them from the quest page. you would just set your quest status for the quest to blow up megaton to be right after you actually blow it up. This command can be used as a workaround for bugged quests or to skip hard/annoying parts of the quest, though use at your own risk as its impossible to predict everything that can happen.

it would look something like this:

```
setstage 00014e9e 60
```

setstage is the command to adjust your quest status, the next number is the ID of the quest Power of the Atom, and stage 60 is the stage where you collect your reward for blowing up megaton in the quest as taken from the Wiki page. (stage 50 is the stage where you press the button, so you probably have to go to 60)

The quest would likely continue as if you had blown up megaton (and people would likely also react like that), but the town would remain. But as noted, this is untested and just an idea. it may blow up megaton for you, but at least you (probably) wont get the bad karma for doing it. It may also cause other events to bug out as the state of the save file if megaton survives would be normally impossible.

Comment: The leading zeroes are unnecessary, so you could use `setstage 14e9e 60` if you wanted. Or `setStage 14e9e 60` to use proper camelCase, which is meaningless for a console command but a good habit if you ever wanted to script things. Because basically, that’s all the console is: a script that gets run line by line as you type them. Also probably good practice for SE answers, as like scripts they are meant to be read.

Comment: @KRyan It's only "proper" if the scripting language in question prefers camelCase. Kind of a silly distinction to make, since many do not....

Comment: @AdamSmith It’s the style favored by Bethesda’s programmers and used in the existing game’s scripts. Consistency is always a good thing.